# Running a command if a MongoDB database doesn't exist

Tags: mongodb, puppet

I'm working with a Vagrant instance. Whenever the VM is booted, there's a test to see if a MongoDB database exists. If it doesn't exist, a Grunt task will create it. The problem is that when the database doesn't exist, my command always returns 1, because Mongo just returns an empty string. Running a wc -m on it, it always returns 1, so my exec never gets called.

My exec{} call:

```
exec { 'grunt --gruntfile /var/www/Gruntfile.js exec:populateDatabase':
  require => Package[['grunt-cli', 'mongodb-server']],
  unless => 'mongo dbName --eval "db.getCollectionNames()" | tail -1'
}
```

Example output from the unless call:

```
[vagrant@localhost www]$ mongo dbName --eval "db.getCollectionNames()" | tail -1
collection_one,collection_two
[vagrant@localhost www]$ mongo dbThatDoesntExist --eval "db.getCollectionNames()" | tail -1

[vagrant@localhost www]$
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Use grep as your test

`grep` will return 0 if it matches and 1 if it doesn't

### Grep patterns

You might need to adjust this based on what mongo is actually returning but, this should cover you:

```
grep "^$" # match the empty string

grep "^   $" # match a string of spaces

grep -v "^$" # match a non-empty string

amir@amir-MacPro:~$ echo "" | grep -v "^$"
amir@amir-MacPro:~$ echo $?
1
```

### Putting it all together

```
exec { 'grunt --gruntfile /var/www/Gruntfile.js exec:populateDatabase':
  require => Package[['grunt-cli', 'mongodb-server']],
  unless => 'mongo dbName --eval "db.getCollectionNames()" | grep -v "^$"'
}
```

Comment: Nice. Also found another, slightly dirty, case where grep solves it as well by changing the whole unless statement to: onlyif => "mongo archetype --eval 'db.getCollectionNames().length' | tail -1 | grep '^0'"

Answer (score 1):

You can also just query directly for the database name like so:

$ echo $dbname

i_am_a_db

$ mongo localhost --quiet --eval "db.getMongo().getDBs().databases.forEach(function(x){if (x.name == '$dbname') { print(x.name);}})"

i_am_a_db